# How to use ddply to add a column to a data frame?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
site   date  var   dil
   1    A    7.4   2 
   2    A    6.5   2
   1    A    7.3   3
   2    A    7.3   3
   1    B    7.1   1
   2    B    7.7   2
   1    B    7.7   3
   2    B    7.4   3
```

I need add a column called `wt` to this dataframe that contains the weighting factor needed to calculate the weighted mean. This weighting factor has to be derived for each combination of `site` and `date`.

The approach I'm using is to first built a function that calculate the weigthing factor:

```
> weight <- function(dil){
                    dil/sum(dil)
                     }
```

then apply the function for each combination of `site` and `date`

```
> df$wt <- ddply(df,.(date,site),.fun=weight)
```

but I get this error message:

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Comment: try `df = ddply(df, .(date, site), transform, wt = weight(dil))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are almost there. Modify your code to use the `transform` function. This allows you to add columns to the data.frame inside `ddply`:

```
weight <- function(x) x/sum(x)

ddply(df, .(date,site), transform, weight=weight(dil))

  site date var dil weight
1    1    A 7.4   2   0.40
2    1    A 7.3   3   0.60
3    2    A 6.5   2   0.40
4    2    A 7.3   3   0.60
5    1    B 7.1   1   0.25
6    1    B 7.7   3   0.75
7    2    B 7.7   2   0.40
8    2    B 7.4   3   0.60
```

Comment: To use ddply you need to have the plyr package installed